# Need MYSQL query for this scenario

Tags: mysql

Consider the following 2 tabls....

```
M.no   budget    created date
1      250M       2010
2      210M       2011
3      200M       1999
4      150M       1994

S.no   Name     
1      Avator
2      Transformers
3      Titanic
4      Dark knight
```

Now i want a query to find ***the movie names which has budget greater than titanic***.

Comment: What have you got so far? Show us where you are stuck: is it on the JOINs, the filtering?

Comment: Are you relating the tables together? Think your either missing some fields or mapping table

Comment: Part of the benefit of homework is to plow through it yourself. JK :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All movie names with their budget:

```
SELECT S.name, M.budget
FROM   S
JOIN   M ON M.no = S.no
```

Budget of Titanic:

```
SELECT M.budget
FROM   S
WHERE  S.Name = 'Titanic'
JOIN   M ON M.no = S.no
```

All movie names which has budget greater than titanic:

```
SELECT S.name
FROM   S
WHERE  M.budget > (
    SELECT M.budget
    FROM   S
    WHERE  S.Name = 'Titanic'
    JOIN   M ON M.no = S.no
)
JOIN   M ON M.no = S.no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.name 
from movies m inner join budgets b on (b.no = m.no)
where b.budget > (select budget 
                  from from movies mm inner join budgets bb on (bb.no = mn.no) 
                  where mm.name = ?)
```